# How to batch multiple elements emitted from source using Akka stream Flow.batch

Tags: akka, reactive-programming, akka-stream

I am using the following code to test the behaviour of akka stream Flow.batch, but I couldn't somehow figure out why the result is not what I expect:

```
  Source(1 to 20)
  .map(x => {
    println(s"received: ${x}")
    x
  })
  .batch(max=3, first => first.toString) {(batch, elem) => {
    batch + "," + elem
  }}
  .runWith(Sink.foreach(x=>{
    Thread.sleep(4000)
    println("Out:" + x)
  }))
```

And here is the output:

`received: 1
received: 2
received: 3
received: 4
Out:1,2,3
received: 5
Out:4
received: 6
Out:5
received: 7
Out:6
received: 8
Out:7
received: 9
Out:8
received: 10
Out:9
received: 11
Out:10
received: 12
Out:11
.... so on ....
received: 19
Out:18
received: 20
Out:19
Out:20`

There are few points I couldn't understand here:

- Firstly, my Sink is much slower. I expect that the item will be batched together before emitted downstream such as: Out: 1,2,3; Out: 4,5,6; Out: 7, 8; Out: 9,10,11 and so on. Instead, it is only batched once (1,2,3), but subsequently element is emitted one by one instead of being batched.
- Why I received 4 items (received: 1, ..., received: 4) at the right beginning while in fact, I only set max=3 (batch(max=3)).
- Because the source is much faster than the sink. I expect that the element should be emitted much faster such as: received: 7, received: 8, received: 9; then Out:7,8,9; But in fact, it is only emitted sporadically one by one and only after Sink's println function is executed.

I have tried to change map to mapAsync but the behaviour is still not what I am looking for:

```
  .mapAsync(1)(x => {
    println(s"received: ${x}")
    Future.successful(x)
  })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no asynchronous boundary anywhere in your code, it will run on a single thread. Basically, while your Thread.sleep() executes no other progress happens in this setup, i.e. batching cannot happen (since the thread is blocked on Thread.sleep). If you have such a setup then you can just use grouped() instead of batch, or maybe groupedWithin(). If you still want to try out batch(), then try a throttle stage instead of adding a sleep. Throttle will not block the thread, so upstream progress (batching) is not affected.